# Jenkins Job DSL get current build result in postBuildScripts shell

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I need to get result of current build execution in postBuildScripts shell call in my Jenkins DSL script. Like `${currentBuild.currentResult}` in Jenkins pipelines with values: SUCCESS, UNSTABLE, or FAILURE

I've searched through DSL doc but havent found any solution for that.

My code is something like this:

```
postBuildScripts {
  steps {
    shell("""echo \$CURRENT_BUILD_STATUS""")
  }
}
```

So how to get this `$CURRENT_BUILD_STATUS` in easiest way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the documentation of the PostBuildScript plugin is missing some interesting parts...

```
job('example') {
  publishers {
    postBuildScripts {
      steps {
        shell('echo $BUILD_RESULT')
      }
    }
  }
}
```